# How to set the text font before rendering text elements?

Tags: reactjs, svg.js

I'm having trouble to place a text element at a certain position. According to [this](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/issues/691) issue, changing the font after adding a text element makes positioning a bit harder.

Seems to me like positioning would be correct if I could set the font before calling `draw.text()`.

Can I do that? How?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** I realized some weird stuff when I was creating a CodeSandBox to improve my question. Check it out:

[image: Edit mz01p10xp9]

I created a rectangle as big as the image, another rectangle 20px smaller on each edge and placed it inside the other, and a text element moved 20px down.

It should align with the inner `rect`. However, by inspecting it, it can be seen that it moved less than 20px down. The weird thing is that, when the `x` parameter of `move` is changed, it moves vertically and snaps to the correct position! However, when the preview is reloaded, the `y` position reverts to the wrong position.

None the less, it gave me an idea...

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround, but I'm not certain if it's reliable.

```
draw.text('Hello, World!')
    .font({ family: 'font-print', size: 20 })
    .move(0, 0).dy(20).dx(60);
```

It doesn't work in the CodeSandBox I've shared, but it works in the actual project I'm working on. For now, at least.